# Django send mail works locally but on server it's not sending mail

Tags: django, apache, email

I have a normally working smpt mail working on localhost but when i put the app on server its not sending mails. I think there is some configuration problem.
I am using apace2 ubuntu server 14.04 and i have placed my project in /var/www/ folder. I am forcing https connection by configuring 000-default.conf file

Settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DEBUG =False

SECRET_KEY = **key**

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [**allowed hosts**]

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


INSTALLED_APPS = (
'index',
'aboutus',
'aboutus.team',
'aboutus.careers',
'aboutus.locations',
'aboutus.board',    
'domainsec',
'projects',
'downloads',
'contactus',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'

ROOT_URLCONF = **urls**

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'antef.wsgi.application'

# Email
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = **emailid**
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = **password**
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

apache_config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteEngine on

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^libwww-perl bad_bot
BrowserMatchNoCase SpammerRobot bad_bot
BrowserMatchNoCase SecurityHoleRobot bad_bot

<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</Location>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>


//apache2.conf
```

Comment: try to set `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` and look on the console log.

Comment: If you search for "gmail django" on Stack Overflow, you will find many users having problems trying to configure it. There are some steps like turning on access for less secure apps that may work for you. However, you may find it easier to use a different mail provider.

Comment: I have turned on the access for less secure app. Its sending emails from localhost but not working on server

Comment: When i try to access from it from browser.It shows "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

Comment: on my terminal: "ImportError: No module named security"

Comment: on changing to EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'. Its working fine. But nott working on smtp. It shows error: SMTPAuthenticationError

Answer (score 0):

Google was using unlock-captcha to allow email sending so i went to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and then i tried to send mail usin python manage.py shell. It then, authenticated the device.